# RabbitMq closes connection abruptly

Tags: php, rabbitmq, celery

I installed celery on my machine and have the tasks.py from tutorial.
It works from python interactive console, but I am trying to call `add` from php.

```
$c = new AMQPConnection();
$c->setLogin('guest')
$c->setPassword('guest')
$c->setHost('localhost')
$c->setVhost('/')
if ($c->connect()) {
    echo "yay";
} else {
    echo "oops";
}
```

I gets to print `yay` and from `tail -f` on rabbit log file I can for sure tell that it is connected.
However, if when connection is successful I try:

```
$channel = new AMQPChannel($c)
```

The log says:

> closing AMQP connection <0.470.0> (127.0.0.1:44024 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
>   connection_closed_abruptly

Any ideas what it's causing it?

Comment: I presume you're using [this PHP AMQP library](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib)? Have you tried using `$c->channel()` rather than `new AMQPChannel($c)`, as shown in the examples?

Comment: Please, provide library name, version, php version, rabbitMQ version, OS and any other info you think may be useful.

Comment: @IMSoP I am using the bare bone AMQP classes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.amqp.php. Initially I went for this lib: https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php, but runs into the same problem. I will also look at the one you linked.
@zaq178miami `celery 3.0.23 (Chiastic Slide)`, `rabbitmq 3.2.1`, `PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep  4 2013 20:00:51)`, `Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS with kernel 2.6.32-26`

Comment: @IMSoP I started working with the library you linked (which is also linked in rabbit docs) and it's working. I don't know why plain AMQP stuff from php breaks like that (I guess AMQP protocol).

Comment: I wasn't actually aware that that PECL extension existed, but I note it relies on a couple of external libraries, so maybe those were giving you issues. As I understand it, php-amqplib is written in plain PHP, and is actively maintained to stay up to date. (The Celery lib you linked to is layered on top of AMQP, not an implementation of it, BTW; there's [an experimental branch](https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php/tree/php-amqplib) for using it with the pure PHP implementation instead of the PECL one.)

Comment: @IMSoP I managed to get it up and running using php-amqplib. If you want to post the above comment as a post, I will vote it as the answer.